# Tried to Publish Project Now my .sln is Lost

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio

I tried to publish my c# project using the steps here:

[Create New Git Repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/creatingrepo?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio)

I was trying to add a Git repo to an existing project.  After creating this, my .sln dissappeared and I cannot find it anywhere, but my debug folder still has everything including the .exe.  Is there anyway I can recover my solution or create a new project using my debug bin?

Comment: Not using your debug bin, no.  If you managed to properly create a git repository for your project, though...that may be a way.  If you open up a developer prompt in your project and type `git ls-files` that should tell you what files git has stored.

Comment: An sln file is just the structure and settings of the solution for Visual Studio. It doesn't contain your code. You might lose a few settings, but it shouldn't be a big deal. When you save in your new environment VS can create a new sln one for you. Just make sure all your projects are imported and you should be fine.

Comment: When I go to Team Explorer >> Solutions >> "There are no solutions found".  In past when I have done this the original solution would show up here, I could click on it, and it would appear in my Solution Explorer.  @zzxyz I am unable to use a command prompt for git on my work computer.